# fullcalendar multiple calendars, how to click prev/next for all calendars

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

So I'm using fullcalendar for this project, having multiple calendars on the same page, each with their own prev/next/today buttons. What I am trying to accomplish is when clicking on the prev/next that it would fire for all the calendars on the page, not just the one it's tied to if that makes sense. I tried using jQuery to accomplish this since they have the same class names, below is an example of a click function I've tried but doesn't quite work how I expected it.

```
$(".fc-next-button").click(function (i) {
        var nextBtn = $('.fc-next-button');
        //alert(nextBtn.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < nextBtn.length; i++) {
            nextBtn[i].click();
        }
    });
```

For example, I have five calendars, when I do click next the function causes the current calendar to move 5 weeks ahead, not all the calendars. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of fullCalendar? And why do you need 5 of them?

Comment: @ADyson Version 3.10.2, and I am displaying multiple people's calendar for the week

Comment: If you're displaying multiple people's calendars, why not use one calendar and put different people's events in different colours to distinguish them. You could use Event Sources to make that easier, if you wanted. You could even use the Scheduler feature to make it clearer, if you're in a position to do so. P.S. Did you realise you are several versions behind the latest version of fullCalendar (v5)?

Comment: @ADyson Yeah I realize im using an odler version and Im trying to keep it seperate in this scenario by design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your loop clicks *all* the "next" buttons. This means effectively that whichever one you clicked on gets clicked twice - once by you manually, and once by the code. Also, the click event gets called over and over because every time you call "click" it triggers the event handler again.

A better approach would be to work out which calendar the button belongs to, and then call fullCalendar's `next` method on all the calendars except that one. Something like this:

```
  $(".fc-next-button").click(function () {
    var calendar = $(this).closest(".calendar");
    $(".calendar").not(calendar).fullCalendar('next');
  });
```

The `$(".calendar")` bit assumes all your calendar elements have a class attribute in common, like in this demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJVMPVy?editable=true&editors=001

Comment: Thanks! this did it for me!